# who is the old spock in star trek movie?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009

Old "Spock" might be from the mirror universe, then how come our world's "J. Kirk" meet him ? And If he is from time then should not old Spock and new Spock cancel each other.

Comment: I know [it's not required to have watched the movie before asking a question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/i-havent-read-the-book-watched-the-movie-may-i-ask-a-question-about-it), but... *did you*?

Answer (score 11):

"Old" Spock is from the original televised series (The Original Series, TOS) which aired from 1966 to 1969. He appeared in six movies following TOS and also made an appearance in The Next Generation (Unification I & II).

As Old Spock explained to James Kirk in the 2009 movie, he was thrown back in time along with Nero and his ship, the Narada. Nero arrived first, appearing some two decades before the time when the Original Series was to take place.

Nero's appearance caused a split in the timeline, separating the original fiction (which includes TOS, TNG, DSN, VOY, ENT and all the previous movies) from the new timeline (Star Trek [2009] and Into Darkness [2013]).

This is why Old Spock and Young Spock can co-exist, because Old Spock is from a future alternate timeline.

Comment: 'Old Spock' is referred to as 'Spock Prime' in the credits.

Answer (score 2):

Old Spock is a Spock from the future. It's a coincidence that Jame Kirk met him at all. They don't cancel each other out despite the different timelines.